# Windows Tiling in Elementary OS 5.1

Tags: release-hera, display, desktop, gala

I have tried to implement a solution to accomplish at least 4 windows tiling, Elementary seems to do only vertical 2 sides windows tiling as detailed here.

I tried and failed with the instructions here:

https://github.com/UbuntuBudgie/window-shuffler
https://github.com/UbuntuBudgie/budgie-extras
https://discourse.ubuntubudgie.org/t/window-shuffler/39/6

I tried adding the ubuntu-budgie-welcome as stated here:

"Ubuntu - use the ubuntu-budgie-welcome snap - and install via Menu - Budgie Applets"
got a bunch of staff installed but the new apps would not run and the budgie-welcome did not start anything.

With one of the instructions I got to the point where it would show the App but it wouldn't do anything.

Any advise on getting this or any other solution that will help me get a big screen better and more easily organized very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this : https://github.com/ssokolow/quicktile However I would recommend to read more about this, because I am not familiar with this solution.

The second option is to use xmonad https://xmonad.org/, just because i3 does not work properly on Elementary OS Juno and Hera. It works on Loki (because of GTK versions which are different in mentioned Elementary OS versions), but I do not see any sense in using older version of Elementary OS. Anyway it is your choice.

Comment: QuickTile actually worked just fine, not exactly the floating style using the mouse that I was hoping for, but still does a great job if you don't mind the 2 actions: focusing the window and using a keyboard combination linked to the window position you want.

Answer (score 0):

Quick tile worked for me too, several installation options available, with more detail at https://ssokolow.com/quicktile/ in addition to the git hub site mentioned above.